# Tree Binary C/C++ Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

i'm kind new in C/C++ programming. I'm trying to write Binary Tree code and find its PreOrder, PostOrder, InOrder structure. So far, i'm doing good with 3 level sub-tree, but when i try to add more child (4 level) i'm getting "Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)" error. I know this is memory allocation violation, i did some research but seriously i don't know how to fix it. Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    string data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};

/* allocates a new node with the NULL left and right pointers. */
struct node* newNode(string data)
{
    struct node* node = (struct node*)
    malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    node->data = data;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;

    return(node);
}

/* Given the tree, print nodes, postorder traversal. */
void printPostorder(struct node* node)
{
    if (node == NULL)
    return;

    // first recur on left subtree
    printPostorder(node->left);
    // then recur on right subtree
    printPostorder(node->right);
    // now deal with the node
    // printf("%d ", node->data);
    cout << node->data;
}

/* print nodes in inorder*/
void printInorder(struct node* node)
{
    if (node == NULL)
    return;
    /* first recur on left child */
    printInorder(node->left);
    /* then print the data of node */
    // printf("%d ", node->data);
    cout << node->data;
    /* now recur on right child */
    printInorder(node->right);
}

/* print nodes in preorder*/
void printPreorder(struct node* node)
{
    if (node == NULL)
    return;
    /* first print data of node */
    // printf("%d ", node->data);
    cout << node->data;
    /* then recur on left sutree */
    printPreorder(node->left);
    /* now recur on right subtree */
    printPreorder(node->right);
}

int main()
{
    struct node *root = newNode("A");
    root->left = newNode("B");
    root->right = newNode("C");
    root->left->left = newNode("D");
    root->left->right = newNode("E");
    root->right->left = newNode("F");
    root->right->right = newNode("G");
    root->left->right->left = newNode("H");
    root->left->right->right = newNode("I");
    root->right->left->left = newNode("J"); // if i delete this, all is fine
    root->right->left->right = newNode("K"); // if i delete this, all is fine

    printf("\n Preorder traversal of binary tree is \n");
    printPreorder(root);
    printf("\n Inorder traversal of binary tree is \n");
    printInorder(root);
    printf("\n Postorder traversal of binary tree is \n");
    printPostorder(root);

    return 0;
}
```

Sorry for my bad english, hope you all understand. And thanks in advance :)

Comment: You should `free` all that allocated memory for starters.

Comment: That's a *crash*. You should run in a debugger to catch it, and the debugger will stop at the location of the crash, letting you examine the call stack (and walk up it too, if needed) and also values of variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One major problem and a source of *undefined behavior* (which might lead to your crash) is that you're using `malloc` to allocate your structures. The problem with that is that it doesn't actually *constructs* your object, it just allocates memory. That means that the string members in the nodes will not be properly constructed and that leads to said *undefined behavior*.

When allocating memory, *of any kind*, in C++ you should use `new`:

```
node* node = new struct node;
```

<sub>Note: You must use the `struct` keyword here because you have a type and a variable with the same name.</sub>

Comment: Or if intented to delay the construction, one may use placement new: `void* ptr = malloc(size); new(ptr) Type(args);`

Comment: so, it is bad practice then to use malloc ?... Thanks @Joachim, i tried your code, and its work fine now...

Comment: @user2869359 `so, it is bad practice then to use malloc ?` In C++ yes (not only bad practice, but just wrong if you expect some constructor running). In C, it´s ok (but that is a different language).

Comment: @user2869359 in this case it's not even bad practice, it's plain wrong. If you use systematically `new` instead of `malloc`, even for very simple cases you are on the safe side.

Comment: Okay guys,... thanks for pointing it out. I have to research more then. Cheers :) !

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg - very nicely explained the malloc behaviour.